# how to create gridview by using JSON images in android

Tags: android, json, gridview

I want to create grid view using JSON.JSON contain image urls.I am reading number of tutorials but i not getting what am want.JSON contain many images(more than 100).please help me how can i solve this issu

Comment: you can use universal image loader for loading images in gridview.

Comment: I guess you are getting image url in json response, right?

Comment: thank you for responding.yes,but universal image loader using urls.but i dont want

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend a different way that works like a charm: Android Query.

You can download jar from [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/list)

```
AQuery androidAQuery = new AQuery(this);
```

As an example:

```
androidAQuery.id(YOUR IMAGEVIEW).image(YOUR IMAGE TO LOAD, true, true); // true, true means image caching in file and in sdcard, if you want to show images fast then keep this true.
```

It's very fast and accurate, and using this you can find many more features like animation when loading, getting a bitmap (if needed), etc.

Comment: Thank you for response.how can i use this jar. give me example please

Comment: @user3814997 In my answer, its the example, just download the jar file and add it to your build path. Then simply paste above 2 lines, give your values, that's it